# Reading files and regex with PYTHON

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

i'm beginner in python and in programming in general, I'd like to create a script in python that can tell if the message was sent or not. after reading log files I've noticed that each message has a **mid** so i got an idea but i'm not sure... if i save all the mid in a list or dictionary i'll be able to compare it with the line that has the mid+**\s**+"**OK**" or "**Error**" here's a part of my log file ( the mid's are incremented by one each time. ) 
can someone help me out to start ? because i have no idea how to start this.. Thanks in advance

```
01:09:25.258 mta    Messages       I Doc O:NVS:SMTP/a.b@x.de R:NVS:SMS.0/+01542xx **mid:6261**
01:09:41.965 mta    Messages       I Rep O:NVS:SMTP/a.b@x.de R:NVS:SMS.0/+01542xx **mid:6261**
01:09:41.965 mta    Messages       I Rep **6261** OK, Accepted (ID: 26)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's not easy to understand what you want

Comment: i have log files, i putted a part of it in the question, it a log file of SMS,VOICE,FAX server and i want to create a script that see if the message was sent or not if it's sent there's an "OK" if not it's an Error like here:

14:12:43.068 mta         Messages       I Rep O:NVS:SMTP/lit@x.de R:NVS:FAXG3/+01510 mid:6418 Repeat 6
14:12:43.068 mta         Messages       I Rep 6418 Error Network

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to look for all the lines that have something like `**1234** Error` in them? Or could a message first have an error and then (after a retry) get changed to an OK?

Comment: yeah it can be there a retry and changed to OK later

Comment: OK, and I guess you only want to find those that finally end up not OK, right?

Comment: no both, that ended up OK and not OK "ERROR" 
saving mid's in a list, and then searching if that mid is followed by an Ok or Error is the solution i think but i don't know how to translate this to python language

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

Let's assume that the log file isn't too big to fit in memory.

```
import re
with open("myfile.log") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
```

First, find all the message IDs in your file:

```
messages = set(m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r"\*\*mid:(\d+)\*\*", data))
```

Now, find all the message IDs for which there exists an `OK` line

```
successes = set(m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r"\*\*(\d+)\*\*\s*OK", data))
```

The difference between the two is the set of IDs that have no `OK` message:

```
failures = messages - successes
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import re

pat = r'\*\*(\d+)\*\* (OK|Error)'
text = open('emailex.txt').read()
d = {}
for res in re.finditer(pat, text):
    d[res.group(1)] = res.group(2)

errors = [mid for mid,status in d.items() if status == 'Error']
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but can you please tell what the two last lines stand for ? i didn't get it

Comment: `d[res.group(1)] = res.group(2)` assigns a dictionary key (mid, the first match group in the pattern 'pat' to a value (status, the second match group in the pattern 'pat'. So it builds a dictionary where the keys are your mids and the values are the statuses.

Comment: `errors = [mid for mid,status in d.items() if status == 'Error']` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that builds a list of all of the mids from the dictionary with a status of 'Error'

Comment: Also, I'd recommend @Tim Pietzcker's method of opening your input file using the with statement. That's generally a better practice when dealing with external resources.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that thank you for your answers i hope i'll succeed !

Comment: @Tim's method will also deal with more non-OK messages, should those exist. Mine only looks for 'OK' or 'Error'.